# How to Use the Carter-Wegman MAC

Tags: authentication, integrity

I have a block of ciphertext, only two hundred characters long, and I want to give it authentication and proof of data integrity.  I have decided upon the Carter-Wegman MAC because I like its randomization and an expert told me this was the way to go.

I am good with GnuPG in the terminal, but, of course, that does not help me here, and I have a good understanding of the basics of cryptography--but my knowledge of programming is limited to a bit of C#.

**What do I need to learn in order to implement Carter-Wegman MACs myself?**
Could someone please give me a clear explanation, or at least a place to start?

Thank you very much.

Comment: By _create_ do you mean implementing it? Or designing a CW-type MAC like VMAC or UMAC?

Comment: @ forest  Thank you. I meant “implement”. I edited my question accordingly.